# Cannot initialize type 'HttpClientHandler'

Tags: c#

Here is the error I get:

> Cannot initialize type 'HttpClientHandler' with a collection
>   initializer because it does not implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Sharepoint_2013_REST_API
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Init
            string baseURL = "";
            string uriString = "";
            string User = "";
            string Password = "";
            string Domain = "";

            System.Net.Http.HttpClient _Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            _Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseURL);
            HttpResponseMessage resp = _Client.GetAsync(uriString).Result;
            string respString = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            _Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { new NetworkCredential(User, Password, Domain)});

            if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.Write("Status code: " + resp.StatusCode);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Hope you can help me resolve this error?

Comment: You have to specify the property name

Comment: Always show your code and error message as a text inside of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to assign NewworkCredential instance to the Credentials property in the object initializer.

```
new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() {{Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain)});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the property to initialize. In this case, it is the `Credentials` property.

```
_Client = 
    new HttpClient(
        new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(User, Password , Domain)
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is incorrect... It should be:

```
new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pwd, domain)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here try it this way:

```
_Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(
    new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler() 
    {Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Password, Domain)});
```

The part with the brackets is called an [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  However, when you don't provide the property you are trying to initialize, i.e. `Credentials =`, the compiler mistakenly thinks you are trying to provide a *collection* initializer, not an *object* initializer.

You would use a collection initializer when initializing a collection, e.g. an array, like this:

```
string[] myStrings = new[] {"first", "second", "third"};
```